# Email message extract has encoding characters

Tags: python, email, character-encoding, rapidminer, email-headers

I am trying to do some text mining on emails which I have exported from my email client (Mail in OS X) just by copying and pasting to a rtf file.
When I attempt to run tf-idf on the files either in python or rapidminer I get features which are clearly not in the message content itself. I wonder where they come from or how I can get rid of them. Perhaps from the headers? For example features such as: fonttbl, colortbl,cocoa rtf,paperw etc. Clearly they are some properties of the email. Where do they come from and how can I remove that more the files or extract only the email contents from the original email messages?
Perhaps this is an encoding issue??

Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to provide sample input for people to see what it is you're looking to get rid of.

Comment: An e-mail reads: `Hello , I m Eli Cher,The apartment belongs to my late father and I have managing and maintaining the apartment.The apartment is 72msq and room is 25msqft  .The lease is --€370/Month/per room/ including the utilities,fridge-freezer,oven, and others.`   However as I run a tf-idf on this email the wordlist shows words fcharset, expnd,fldrslt, helvetica, helveticaneue,hyperlink, fonttbl, viewh, vieww, bold, blue. Words that don't appear in the email but seem to be properties of the email on the backend or something.

Comment: I found out that this is standard rtf syntax (tagging). Trying to find a regex to strip the syntax from the message itself now.

Comment: Ah, I'm not familiar with that syntax so I hope you figure it out! If you find a solution, feel free to post it as a self answer for anyone else who comes across your question.

Comment: I've created this regex - (\\[A-Za-z]+(\d+|\d?)){1,}|(\\'[A-Za-z]+) . which seems to do a pretty good job but it is not heavily tested yet.

Comment: So now I try to find all possible patterns in a specific txt file and I want to remove those patterns from the file. The output of the `re.findall` module returns a list. How can I achieve that? This is the code I have so far `pattern = (\\\\[A-Za-z]+(\d+|\d?)?)` , `output = re.findall(pattern, doc)`. the variable doc holds the document contents via `open(path).read()`.

Comment: Instead of finding them what you want to do is use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub). It's like `str.replace` but it uses regex. You could call `re.sub(pattern, '', string)` to strip out anything that matches `pattern` in `string`.

Comment: Thanks @SuperBiasedMan that works great

Comment: Glad that worked! Feel free too post an answer showing how you solved it, in case anyone else has the same problem and finds your question.

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan here is my current solution though it is far from perfect: `(\\\\[A-Za-z]+(\d+|\d?)?)`. Keep in mind it is a python based regex. My output for one of the strings I am using still includes a bunch of white spaces and rich-text-file tagging which depict the font-name. String example:`{ ArialMT;}
{;;;;}   
Hi, \
\
 I am glad that you are still interested in`...